# Format a Column Based on Date and Specific Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Columns H-AB contain individual dates,
Column A contains text,
Column F contains dates.

I want to conditionally format column H if $A8 says "Project Completion" *and* H$7 is equal to the date in $F8.

I've really struggled with formatting dependent on multiple variables so I could use some help. When I select the area I want to apply the rule to and test, it formats a single cell in the correct column two rows above my input. Can't figure out why.

EDIT

Thank y'all for the responses, but it seems like maybe my wording wasn't great. [What I have so far vs what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyW1n.png). My formula is **=and($a8="Project Completion", $f8=h$7)**
 Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: What's your conditional format formula?  If you select the entire column, then the `ActiveCell` (which is important for conditional format formulas) will be `H1`.  Knowing this, your conditional format formula should be `=AND($A1="Project Completion",H$7=$F1)`

Comment: Record a macro with test case(do all u need manually) and generalize it.

Comment: It would have be helpful if your image contained the row/column names as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that data is moving down rows. And the format should apply on a row by row basis.

Select Column H (or relevant rows in Column H) and enter this formula:

```
=AND(A8="Project Completion",$F8=H7)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the result I've gotten already. Maybe my wording wasn't great - H$7:AB$7 have the dates and I want to format the whole column below the date that meets the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a typo on your question having fixed H$7.

If validation is by row:

```
=(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()) = "Project Completion")*(INDIRECT("F" & ROW())=INDIRECT("H" & ROW()))
```

If validation is by row and value on column F is equal to H7:

```
=(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()) = "Project Completion")*(INDIRECT("F" & ROW())=H$7)
```

If validation is only for row 8 and F8 is equal to H7:

```
=($A$8 = "Project Completion")*($F$8 = H$7)
```